# Using javascript split on a substring

Tags: javascript, split

I am using javascript in a Domino environment.

I am trying to split an HTML string into an array to work on specific items within it.  The separator I want to use is the ending table row delimiter `</TR>`.  I would like some help to figure out how to do this.  From what I see, most examples are working on a single character and not the group of characters.

Comment: consider to add an example code or rephrase your question

Answer (score 1):

From my Chrome console:

```
var a = "Hello</tr>There</tr>King";
> undefined
a.split("</tr>");
> ["Hello", "There", "King"]
```

Case insensitive version -- warning -- ugly:

```
var a ="Hello</tr>there</TR>King";
> undefined
a.split(/\<\/tr\>/i)
> ["Hello", "there", "King"]
```

You'll need to read up on regular expressions though.

Comment: That's exactly what I was doing and it wasn't working.  It just hit me though, that it's probably case sensitive.

Comment: @Thomos - When passing a string as the split, yes it is case sensitive.  Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, this helps. I'm still getting a single string returned. Here's the few lines I'm actually using. The field used in the first line contains the HTML that resulted from another process on the page. The alert tells me there is one element to "rec".

var getText = document.getElementById("#{id:inputText3}").innerHTML;
var rec = getText.split(/\<\/tr\>/i);
alert(rec.length.toString());

Comment: @ThomasScott -- Update your question with the value of `getText`

Comment: I'm sorry.  I definitely had a data issue.  I will get back to this once I know that I have good data to work with.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If in doubt, check [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

This gives you the parameters for `split` and an indication of how it works

Answer (score 0):

jQuery could help too

```
var $rows = $("#table1 tr"), items=[];
$rows.each(function(i,row) {
  items.push[row.text()];
});
```